# How to display an image for an archive page

Tags: php, wordpress

Created a Custom Post Type for speakers on the site. Each will have a separate page and an archive page, where all speakers will be displayed in the form of cards. How can I set an image for a card on an archive page? Now, in the admin panel, the box with the choice of image for the post does not appear. Although I seem to have correctly added add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array('speakers')).
What could be the problem?

function.php:

```js
function twentytwentytwo_support() {

  // Add support for block styles.
  add_theme_support('wp-block-styles');

  // Add support for thumbnails.
  add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array('speakers'));

  // Enqueue editor styles.
  add_editor_style('style.css');

  // Menus
  register_nav_menus(
    array(
      'menu-1' => esc_html__('Primary', 'pediatric-integrative-medicine'),
      'menu-2' => esc_html__('Footer', 'pediatric-integrative-medicine'),
    )
  );

}

endif;

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'twentytwentytwo_support');

function pediatric_create_post_type() {
  register_post_type('speakers',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __('Speakers'),
        'singular_name' => __('Speaker'),
        'supports' => array('thumbnail'),
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );
}
add_action('init', 'pediatric_create_post_type');
```

archive.php:

```html
<ul class="speakers-list">
  <?php
     $args = array(  
     'post_type' => 'speakers',);
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
            while ($loop->have_posts()) :
      $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="speaker-img">
          <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/speaker-1.png">
        </div>
        <div class="speaker-name">
          <p>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="speaker-city">
          <p>
            Fribourg
          </p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you saying that your code sample is not working? If it is not working, what result are you seeing? Or are you asking for a way to display images without hard-coding URLs? If hard-coded URLs is the problem you could be looking for the [get_the_post_thumbnail_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) function.

Comment: I need to replace a hard-coded path in the div class "speaker-img" into the image to make it possible to choose it myself. I tried the_post_thumbnail( ) but it didn't work. How can I make it so that in the admin panel I can choose it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few items to consider:

1. Thumbnail support is enabled in your theme,
2. Thumbnail support is enabled in your Custom Post Type, and
3. *get_the_post_thumbnail_url()* (or some variant of it) is used to get the URL for your `<img>` tag.

### Theme thumbnail support

Details are available on this WordPress documentation page for [Featured image](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/#enabling-support-for-featured-image).

### Custom post type thumbnail support

You can add thumbnail support to your custom post type by using the *supports* property in the call to *register_post_type()*:

```php
  register_post_type( 'speakers', 
      array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Speakers' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'speaker' ),
        'supports' => array( 'thumbnail' )
      ),
       'public' => true,
       'has_archive' => true,
      )
  );
```

Details about the *supports* property are available on this WordPress documentation page for [register_post_type](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#supports). Support for thumbnails can also be added using the [add_post_type_support()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_post_type_support/) function.

### Use get_the_post_thumbnail_url()

The [get_the_post_thumbnail_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) function has this signature:

```php
get_the_post_thumbnail_url( int|WP_Post $post = null, string|int[] $size = 'post-thumbnail' )
```

Note the `$size` parameter. It might affect how you configure your `speaker-img` CSS properties.

To use this function, your *speaker-img* code could look like this:

```php
      ...
      <a href="#">
        <div class="speaker-img">
          <?php $img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $loop->post->ID ); ?>
          <img src="<?php echo $img_url ?>">
        </div>
      ...
```

As described on the WordPress documentation page for [Featured image](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/#setting-a-featured-image), you can choose the thumbnail image yourself by using the *Featured image* option on the Add and Edit Post admin pages.